# CSS Shapes shape-outside: url; float inconsistency

Tags: css, css-shapes

When I use `shape-outside: url(anyimage.png)` and float it to the right, the text around it wraps nicely as intended, but when I float it to the left, the text to the right wraps around the the edge of a rectangle.

Any idea why this should be so? I have tried with several transparent shapes and the text wraps nicely when the image is floated to the right, but when its floated to the left, the text defaults to a wrapping around a rectangle.

Any idea if this is a known bug? I'm using the latest version of Chrome (46.0.2490.86 m) and only interested in implementation on **Chrome**.

Here is the image of float issue attached

[image]
Also here is the image of the circle png

[image]

and here is the CSS:

```
.element{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  float:right;
  shape-outside: url("circle_new.png");
  shape-image-threshold: 0px;
  shape-margin: 10px;
}
```

**

*added after first response*: let me clarify, am looking for a reason for the inconsistent behaviour  of `shape-outside: url`. I understand I could very well use `circle()` as pointed out by the first answer, but I **want this to work for all shapes**, that is why I am seeking enlightenment specifically on the issue of **`shape-outside: url`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error

```
.element{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  float:right;
  shape-outside: url("circle_new.png");
  shape-image-threshold: 0px;   /* error */
  shape-image-threshold: 0;  /* in the range 0 - 1 */
  shape-margin: 10px;
}
```

Since you don't post an example, it's difficult to tell, but this property is subject to cross-origin issues. So another posible problem would be the image being blocked.

Have you checked the console ?

Note that the fact that you are **seeing** the image does not imply that it isn't being blocked in the shape-outside url

[image: console log]

Comment: thanks, but don't understand what you mean by the image being "blocked". do explain, also what exactly am i to check in the console (and how, if possible).

Comment: Added screenshot of an CORS error (Chrome devtools)

Comment: yes - the console is showing this very error. how does one deal with this issue?

Comment: The image must be hosted in your own domain. Copy it to your server if you need to.

Comment: the img already exists in the same location as the index.html. i tried creating a .htaccess with  this line in it: Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

Comment: Thanks - I used prepros and it's working fine. I guess the prepros.cfg took care of the CORS issue. This has introduced me to a whole new area I have to explore. thanks again.

Comment: Happy that it helped !

Answer (score 1):

If your aim is to make the text wrap around a circle, you should use `circle()` for the shape-outside property :

```css
p{
  width:400px;
  text-align:justify;
}
.element {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    float:right;
    shape-outside: circle(50%);
    shape-image-threshold: 0px;
    shape-margin: 10px;
    background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtBMS.png');
    background-size:contain;
}

p+p .element{
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur quis quam ex. Fusce sagittis purus mi, ut volutpat lorem venenatis id. In varius sodales dui ut molestie. <span class="element"></span>
Phasellus pretium metus id massa volutpat, sed gravida nisl fringilla. Quisque eu gravida lacus, in mollis risus. Duis et est sodales, iaculis mi et, scelerisque elit. Vivamus in massa at lectus hendrerit condimentum. Curabitur nec dignissim turpis, elementum viverra urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nunc eget ullamcorper augue. Aliquam sit amet quam feugiat, finibus lacus ac, luctus mi. In quis leo nec lectus porttitor pulvinar mollis vitae tellus. Fusce turpis quam, fringilla at aliquam sit amet, porta ac purus. Suspendisse ac faucibus dolor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam mauris metus, pharetra vitae velit eu, suscipit molestie odio.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur quis quam ex. Fusce sagittis purus mi, ut volutpat lorem venenatis id. In varius sodales dui ut molestie. <span class="element"></span>
Phasellus pretium metus id massa volutpat, sed gravida nisl fringilla. Quisque eu gravida lacus, in mollis risus. Duis et est sodales, iaculis mi et, scelerisque elit. Vivamus in massa at lectus hendrerit condimentum. Curabitur nec dignissim turpis, elementum viverra urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nunc eget ullamcorper augue. Aliquam sit amet quam feugiat, finibus lacus ac, luctus mi. In quis leo nec lectus porttitor pulvinar mollis vitae tellus. Fusce turpis quam, fringilla at aliquam sit amet, porta ac purus. Suspendisse ac faucibus dolor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam mauris metus, pharetra vitae velit eu, suscipit molestie odio.</p>
```

*Note that I also added `text-align:justify;` so the text wraps closer to the shape on the right*

Comment: Thanks. `circle()` works very well and has no problems. I want to know why **`shape-outside: url`** is acting inconsistent.

Comment: I belive there is an issue with png images (btw I don't think the text in your image is wraping at all on either float sides). Have you tried with an SVG image?

Comment: Just tried with svg; has the same issue. Also text-align:justify just makes it more obvs that float: right also has the same issue of no real wrapping around the form (as you pointed out).

Answer (score 1):

In both situations the text isn’t all aligned to the right. This behavior is normal. The text starts at the same point on the left and ends at different points on the right, since each line has a different length. It doesn’t have much to do with your image really.

The best way around this is to use `shape-outside: circle();` and set a proper number arugment inside `circle()`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I specifically wish to know why `shape-outside: url` isn't working.

Comment: For the reason I just explained. If it is still unclear please let me know so I can explain in a different way.